# Contact form works, sends email, information is missing

Tags: php, html, forms

I created this contact form from below. Everything works great up to the point where I am trying to add another section to the “body” in the email form. The first message works that appends to the body, but I cannot get say another section in the HTML form to work.

What is wrong with this form? Thank you for your help.

```
<form method="post" action="emailform.php">             
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"class="large" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name"/></li><!--Basically gave a name here-->

        <li>   
        <label for="idlabel">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter your email"/></li><!--Basically gave a name here-->

         <label for="message2"> <textarea name="message2" maxlength="800" rows="6"
        cols="23"></textarea></li></ul>




        <li><label for="message">Enter Your Message Below</label> 
            <textarea name="message" maxlength="800" rows="6"
        cols="23"></textarea></li></ul><!--Basically gave a name here and removed label as name-->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>    
</form>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Emailing Form Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (empty($_POST)) {
    print "<p>No data was submitted.</p>";
    print "</body></html>";
    exit();
}

/* Creates function that removes magic escaping, if it's been applied, from values and then removes extra newlines and returns to foil spammers. Thanks Larry Ullman! */
function clear_user_input($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $value=stripslashes($value);
    $value= str_replace( "\n", '', trim($value));
    $value= str_replace( "\r", '', $value);
    return $value;
}


/* Create body of email message by cleaning each field and then appending each name and value to it. */

$body ="Here is the data that was submitted:\n";
//Fetching the form fields here
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$message2 = $_REQUEST['message2'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];



/* Removes newlines and returns from $email and $name so they can't smuggle extra email addresses for spammers */
$email   = clear_user_input($email);
$name    = clear_user_input($name);

$body   .= clear_user_input($message); + clear_user_input($message2); //Appending the message to the body of the email

/* Create header that puts email in From box along with name in parentheses and sends Bcc to alternate address. Change yourmail@yourdomain.com to the Bcc email address you want to include. */
$from='From: '. $email . "(" . $name . ")" . "\r\n" . 'Bcc: yourmail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";

// Creates intelligible subject line that also shows me where it came from
$subject = 'New User Sign Up!';

/* Sends mail to the address below with the form data submitted above. Replace yourmail@yourdomain.com with the email address to which you want the data sent. */
mail ('yourmail@yourdomain.com', $subject, $body, $from);
?>

<p>Thank you.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$body .= clear_user_input($message); + clear_user_input($message2);`

to

`$body .= clear_user_input($message).clear_user_input($message2);`

Also you might want to add lots of checks on validity of all passed values (valid emails, empty values ect..), as it is you will get lots of empty or spammy messages.